# Redirect GDI Code directly to PDF?

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, pdf-generation, gdi

Is there a way to redirect an existing GDI code to a PDF file ?

I have an existing .NET / C# project, which prints a page by creating a PrintDocument object (PrintPageEventHandler, Graphics...). Now this application should also create PDF files.

I am looking for a solution which doesn't need to setup a printer driver in the system. The PDF generation should happen directly in our applicaton, without the use of an external printer driver.

We use VStudio 2013 and .NET 4.5

Comment: I think this is not possible. You either use a printer, or you write new code to use some kind of PDF generation API.

Comment: In case it helps, [the company I work for sells a PDF printer driver](http://www.amyuni.com/en/developer/pdfconverter/) that you can install/uninstall programmatically from your application before/after every print job (admin required the first time, usually upon installing your app), so it can be "almost" invisible to the end user.

Comment: @yms - the product has interesting features, but these are not needed by my applicaton. And if I need "admin", then I could also use any other PDF printer, like FreePDF etc. In the moment, I'm looking at a solution with ghostscript, if this works, I will report here.

Comment: I suppose you know that [there are restrictions on using the AGPL version of ghostscript in a commercial closed-source application](http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Commprod.htm).

Answer (score 0):

PDFsharp uses an XGraphics objects that is meant to implement the functions of the Graphics object.

It depends on your code how difficult it will be to adapt it to the XGraphics object.

PDFsharp site:
http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/Graphics-sample.ashx

Downloads available here:
http://pdfsharp.codeplex.com/releases

Comment: I already have had a look at PDFSHarp, but I found that its XGraphics class is NOT derived from the Graphics class. In fact, it is a separate class. Since I have existing code, this is not really useful for me.

Comment: @Georg: Yes, it's the other way around: an XGraphics object contains a Graphics objects (when needed). So when changing your code for the XGraphics object once, you will be able to draw on PDF and on Graphics objects. Best solution I know - and it works without printer driver. Also open source and free for commercial use.

Comment: Thank you! I gave it a try again. I found that PDFSharp is really a tremendously great library, but still, it has its limits. It begins with the fact that my project is using MILLIMETERS as a unit all over, and PDFSharp is only using POINT  ...

Then, there is no "XRectangleF" object, only XRectangle, etc. 

It seems like PDFSharp tried to re-invent the wheel... Would be probably better to write a library which takes a Metafile out of a Graphics, and then creates a PDF out of it.